# how to make yasnippet case insensitive

Tags: yasnippet

I want yasnippet to expand both "Cp" and "cp" into the same, say, "\citep{}".

How can this be done?  Is there a way to make yasnippet case insensitive?  As a quick-and-dirty solution, I tried creating yasnippet description files for both "cp" and "Cp", but only one of them is being recognized.  Any ideas?

Comment: 'I tried creating yasnippet description files for both "cp" and "Cp"' - Did you give them different `#name:`s?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  If the `#name:` field is different (e.g., `citep` and `Citep`), it works.  It is a quite a bit of a hassle, though, to do this manually for a large number of snippets.  It would be nice if case insensitivity could be configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following advice:

```el
(defun yas--downcase-key (args) ; args = (table key)
  (cl-callf downcase (nth 1 args))
  args)
(advice-add 'yas--fetch :filter-args #'yas--downcase-key)
```

But there should probably be some kind of yasnippet option for this.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it would be nice if this was an option that could be configured globally as well as in a per snippet basis.

Comment: @scaramouche: per-snippet would be more difficult. Opened an issue to track this: https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/issues/635